# TypeScript: How do you apply "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" to node_modules only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

For context, I'm trying to apply a workaround to this issue: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-proxy-agent/issues/62

The typescript in that library does not compile, the error being `node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.d.ts:2:8 - error TS1192: Module '"net"' has no default export.` This prevents my own code from compiling.  The work around is to have this in my tsconfig.json:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

I don't want this applying to all of my code, just this library/all node_modules. How can I turn this setting on only for my node_modules?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issue. I don't understand how people can release built code that is not compliant

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I don't think I ever did. As for your last sentence, I can empathize; to be honest, I have no idea where to learn how to be compliant in this regard either.